# Unable to resolve Maven dependencies in Eclipse/m2e

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I am running Eclipse Kepler with m2e.  Java classes do not compile because of missing dependencies, and it appears that at least part of the problem is that Eclipse cannot resolve plugins in the POM.

Some example error messages:

`Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)`

Part of the problem may be that the POM references Maven 3.2, and the embedded Maven in m2e is 3.0.

How would I fix this?

When I run mvn from the command line, dependencies get downloaded and resolved fine, and I can compile.  So I think this is mostly an Eclipse/m2e issue.

Comment: Darn - you're right.  I thought it was something specific with a version mismatch, but simply adding the `<pluginManagement>` element fixed it.

Comment: Hi, try to update maven plugin for eclipse.